# Spring Throws NoSuchMethodError Exception

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-data

When I'm trying to run the below code

```
@Override
public List<EventDetails> process(int event_status) throws EventDetailDataException {
    String sql="select * from MicroServiceEventDetails where  event_status=?";
    List<EventDetails> EventDetailsList = template.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<EventDetails>(EventDetails.class),new Object[] {event_status});
    return EventDetailsList;
}
```

It throws the following exception and here's the error log:-

```
Apr 02, 2017 6:26:04 AM org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler handleError
SEVERE: Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.getSharedInstance()Lorg/springframework/core/convert/ConversionService;
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper.<init>(BeanPropertyRowMapper.java:91)
at com.syntel.boot.dao.EventProcessDaoImpl.process(EventProcessDaoImpl.java:38)
at com.syntel.boot.services.EventDetailServiceImpl.process(EventDetailServiceImpl.java:73)
at com.syntel.boot.scheduler.microeventschudler.eventExcuter(microeventschudler.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Maybe maven dependencies would be the reason i'm not sure, help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Maven/Gradle, any build tool. 
I was working on a spring MVC project and added LDAP functionality, however I added the LDAP jar dependency on the top of the dependency list in pom.xml and the jar version I used, utilized a lower version of spring core which did not have the ConversionService class.  I identified this by back tracking to what was the most recent change to the Spring jar versions I made(i.e. added ldap libs) and using the Maven - Dependency hierarchy tab to identify what had changed. Once I removed the new dependency. did a clean, install, add the dependencies to the bottom of the list. The issue was fixed.

[image: ensure your spring core jar is the highest version of versions refered by other jars]

Your resolved dependencies should have the highest spring core version referenced on the column on the left. Any lower version should be omitted. In the screenshot, notice that spring core 4.3.9 is omitted for 4.3.4. Avoid this by adding the dependencies that use lower spring core versions below those which use higher versions.